# How to design mongodb structure if i want to return other information after query date?

Tags: mongodb

In my example a movie theater has two movies, i hope that after query `{ $gte: ISODate("2018-03-27 19:00:00.000Z")}`, i can get movie `Pacific Rim Uprising` with `21:00`、`21:40` and `Tomb Raider` with `19:30`

Here is my document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abb086677d96df7015c56c6"),
    "theater" : "Madou",
    "movie" : {
        "moviePhoto" : [ 
            "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w420/i/o/production/movies/March2018/GD9otOLc6d3eprWHC1Ve-2757x4000.jpg", 
            "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w420/i/o/production/movies/March2018/MueV83b8cYC28yRbknIT-3254x4650.jpg"
        ],
        "releasedTime" : [ 
            [ 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T12:20:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T14:30:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T15:10:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T16:40:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T18:50:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T21:00:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T21:40:00.000Z")
            ], 
            [ 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T13:00:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T17:20:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T19:30:00.000Z")
            ]
        ],
        "enName" : [ 
            "Pacific Rim Uprising", 
            "Tomb Raider"
        ]
    }
}
```

I looking for the tutorial , all they teach is only one document with a date. Query the date and get other information obviously.

I am confused with it in my case.

Any one can teach me how to restructure my database or share any tutorial link ?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain your requirement clearly in the post.

Comment: I think you need to rethink/simplify your data structure. Asides this one, you're going to have a lot of pain and headaches when you do queries.

Comment: Its some kind of like train timatable if query 18:00~20:00 then show all of the train is within 18:00~20:00 @RahulRaj

Comment: @Mikey Do you mean i should reduce my database root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restructure your collection as follows: each theatre has an array of movies where each movie has a name, photo, and release times.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abb086677d96df7015c56c6"),
    "theater" : "Madou",
    "movies" : [{
        "name": "Pacific Rim Uprising",
        "photo": "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w420/i/o/production/movies/March2018/GD9otOLc6d3eprWHC1Ve-2757x4000.jpg",
        "releasedTimes" : [ 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T12:20:00.000Z"), 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T14:30:00.000Z"), 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T15:10:00.000Z"), 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T16:40:00.000Z"), 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T18:50:00.000Z"), 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T21:00:00.000Z"), 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T21:40:00.000Z")
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "Tomb Raider",
        "photo": "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w420/i/o/production/movies/March2018/MueV83b8cYC28yRbknIT-3254x4650.jpg",
        "releasedTimes" : [ 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T13:00:00.000Z"), 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T17:20:00.000Z"), 
            ISODate("2018-03-27T19:30:00.000Z")
        ]
    }]
}
```

In terms of getting movies with only release times greater than specified date, you will need to use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) - particularly a combination of [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to filter out child arrays. You can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38321263/1022914) to get a general idea why it is written this way (though maybe there's a simpler way).

```
db.theatres.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        theater: true,
        movies: { 
            $filter: {
                input: {
                    $map: { 
                        input: "$movies", 
                        as: "movie", 
                        in: { 
                            name: "$$movie.name", 
                            photo: "$$movie.photo", 
                            releasedTimes: { 
                                $filter: { 
                                    input: "$$movie.releasedTimes", 
                                    as: "time", 
                                    cond: { $gte: [ "$$time", ISODate("2018-03-27 19:00:00.000Z") ] }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                as: "movie",  
                cond: "$$movie"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

After testing this on Robo3T, the result will be

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abb086677d96df7015c56c6"),
    "theater" : "Madou",
    "movies" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Pacific Rim Uprising",
            "photo" : "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w420/i/o/production/movies/March2018/GD9otOLc6d3eprWHC1Ve-2757x4000.jpg",
            "releasedTimes" : [ 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T21:00:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T21:40:00.000Z")
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Tomb Raider",
            "photo" : "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w420/i/o/production/movies/March2018/MueV83b8cYC28yRbknIT-3254x4650.jpg",
            "releasedTimes" : [ 
                ISODate("2018-03-27T19:30:00.000Z")
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You may need to add [additional stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) to filter out theatres with movies having no released times, if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much Mikey. Its very clear. I will try to restructure for your answer !

Comment: I have restructured my db structure and query my `releasedTime` succeed. Thank you again !